# Python while true loops

Tags: python

**I have this code:**

```
Roll=[1,2,4]
for h in Roll:
    if set(Roll)=={4,5,6}:
        print('Automatic win! Banker wins all bets! Round ends!')
        break
    elif len(set(Roll))==2 and Roll.count(h)==2:
        Roll.remove(h)
        Roll.remove(h)
        if Roll[0]==1:
            print('Banker lost')
        elif Roll[0]==2:
            banker_score=Roll[0]
            print('Banker scored ',banker_score)
        elif Roll[0]==3:
            banker_score=Roll[0]
            print('Banker scored ',banker_score)
        elif Roll[0]==4:
            banker_score=Roll[0]
            print('Banker scored ',banker_score)
        elif Roll[0]==5:
            banker_score=Roll[0]
            print('Banker scored ',banker_score)
        elif Roll[0]==6:
            print('Automatic win! Banker wins all bets! Round ends!')
    elif set(Roll)=={1,2,3}:
        print('Banker lost')
        break
    elif Roll[0]==Roll[1]==Roll[2]:
        print('Automatic win! Banker wins all bets! Round ends!')
        break
```

**This code is part of a bigger code so the list elements(here they are stable),change because i want to check if my code works.Till this point my code works fine but i have 1 problem.If the combination of the list elements isnt in one of the if,elif the code should re-run the whole process *printing Banker rolls again.**My question is: will a while true loop help me here?****

Comment: Use a while loop with setting a variable to boolean true. If your condition arrives, set that variable to false. Then the loop will be terminated

Comment: the body of the loop would run forever unless one of the conditions with `break` gets hit. So no, you cannot just replace your for loop with `while True`. Instead, you should show the larger picture. It's quite possible that you don't need a loop at all at that stage.

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG any ideas on how i can print" Banker rolls again "while looping?

Comment: @PanagiotisStavropoulos just write the print statement just after the loop starts.

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG oh okay thank you